# Can I Assign Pod to a NIC?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have 1 master 1 node kubernetes cluster. On the node there are 2 network interface cards (in the same IP block and same sub-net but different IP).

**Can i assign my pods to a special NIC ?**

For example in docker we execute below command:

`docker run -p 192.168.1.15:80:80 nginx`

With above command nginx will run only on **IP 192.168.1.15**

So, can i achieve this on kubernetes?

Comment: This would be totally up to your CNI provider.  Usually Kubernetes pods run on a private overlay network.  A Service would provide external access to pods, but the standard service settings don’t bind to specific hosts or interfaces (the closest thing is a NodePort service which allocates a port on every host, and I think every interface too).

Comment: Another valid path would be to write a non-Kubernetes reverse proxy (say, a minimal nginx installation) that listened on only a specific interface and proxied to the NodePort service.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your docker example `docker run -p 192.168.1.15:80:80 nginx`

you can use service [without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

> Because this Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint
>   object is not created automatically. You can manually map the Service
>   to the network address and port where it’s running, by adding an
>   Endpoint object manually:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.1.15
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

Answer (score -1):

From my quick research K8S does not seem to support this. You can assign a `Service` to an IP address and port but pods are meant to be disposable and non-critical. Networking routing is handled by the Ingress Controller. If a pod is associated with a specific IP then the pod is no longer a commodity concept but rather a known quantity.

My assumption is that you want to be able to access the pod directly, if that is the case try the port forwarding mechanic that leverages the aforementioned Ingress Controller.

Comment: No actually i would like to use a kubernetes node as internal load balancer with ingress.But i can assign pods only 1 interface